# why android.hardware.telephony feature is being added automatically in android app

Tags: android, telephonymanager

While releasing the apk to play store, I found out that the my app requires the `android.hardware.telephony` feature but I haven't added it in manifest anywhere. I have also check the merged manifest in android studio and it also does not contain this feature so I think no third party sdk is adding this. What could be the source of this feature?

For reference, I have following permissions declared in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also, when I make it optional using below code, the app is available on devices without this feature:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

So why is required by default without adding it anywhere?

Comment: Did this issue got resolved?

Comment: @BharathKumar It most likely is now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55899751/608312

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Play automatically adds some features, depending on which permissions you have requested.

As you have requested `READ_SMS` and `RECEIVE_SMS` permissions, this implies you use the `telephony` feature. So, Google Play reacts as if you had the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="true" />
```

When you manually add this and declare it `required="false"`, this tells Google Play that whilst you do ask for the permission, you can handle the case where the user does not have the `telephony` feature.

This is confirmed via [this note in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Features):

> Note: Some system permissions implicitly require the availability of a device feature. For example, if your app requests permission to access to BLUETOOTH, this implicitly requires the FEATURE_BLUETOOTH device feature.

The full list of permissions and the feature requirements implied is [available here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), and includes your situation:

[image: sms permissions implying telephony]

Finally, with your `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` you are also declaring a feature requirement on `android.hardware.location`, just for your information.

There's also further detailed information over on [the GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112920/115906).

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the dependencies / modules / libraries your project is using is adding that requirement to your `Android Manifest`.

To investigate open your main `Android Manifest` file in `Android Studio`, and click on the `Merged Manifest` tab at the bottom of the page.

This will show you a view of the final merged Manifest, along with sources of each line.

Read more about this here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts

**HOW TO FIX**

If you wish to avoid adding that requirement to your final Manifest, you can use Node Markers in your Manifest to control how the merge works.

Read more about Node markers here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers

e.g. try this:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false"
    tools:node="replace" />
```

Comment: The feature is not there in the merged manifest. I specified it in the question also.